# Jenkins: gitlabCommitStatus is not working

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

My enviroment is the next:

-Jenkins 2.46.1

-Gitlab plugin 1.4.5

-GitLab Community Edition 8.14.3

I have a multibranch pipeline configured. I have tried with:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
      gitLabConnection('MY_GITLAB')
      gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'jenkins')
    }
    triggers {
        gitlab(triggerOnPush: true, triggerOnMergeRequest: true, branchFilterType: 'All')
    }
    stages {

        stage("build") {
            steps {
                gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'build') {
                withMaven(
                            maven: 'maven3', // Maven installation declared in the Jenkins "Global Tool Configuration"
                            mavenSettingsConfig: 'MY_ID', // Maven settings.xml file defined with the Jenkins Config File Provider Plugin
                            mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {
                                // Run the maven build
                                sh "mvn clean install"
                            }
                }               
            }
        }

        stage("paralelo") {
        steps {
            parallel (
                    phase1: { sh "echo phase1" },
                    phase2: { sh "echo phase2" }
                    )
                }
        }
    }
}
```

It works without erros but i dont see the commit status in my Gitlab. Without erros in production.log from gitlab.

Thanks to all!

Comment: Do you have a multibranch pipeline job? Because probably you are looking for [this](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#git-configuration-for-multibranch-pipelineworkflow-jobs) configuration

Answer (score 2):

You will need to wrap it in `gitlabBuilds(build: ["jenkins", "build"]) { }`.

This will communicate the statusses that are coming. Note that the value needs to be exactly the same as you are using in `gitlabCommitStatus('..')`.

The layout should be:

```
checkout scm
gitlabBuilds(builds: ["1.", "2.",..."n."]) {
    gitlabCommitStatus(name: "1.") { ... }
    gitlabCommitStatus(name: "2.") { ... }
    ...
    gitlabCommitStatus(name: "n.") { ... }
}
```

where off course the name you can choose whatever you like, as long as it matches the values in `gitlabBuilds.builds`.

Make sure your `gitlabConnection` is working correctly.

Comment: I have now this but it doesn´t work:

...
    options {
      gitLabConnection('MY_GITLAB')
      gitlabBuilds(builds: ["build","paralelo"])
 }
  ....
    stages {
      
  stage("build") {
   steps {
    gitlabCommitStatus(name: "build") {
    .....
    }    
   }
  }
 }